# let loop returns unexpected results

Tags: scheme

Can anyone tell me why the result of

```
(remove (list 1 2 3) 1)
```

where `remove` is defined by

```
(define (remove ls x)
(let loop((ls0 ls) (ls1 '()))
 (if (null? ls0)
     (reverse ls1)
     (let ((ls2 (if (eqv? x (car ls0))
                    ls1
                    (cons (car ls0) ls1))))
       loop (cdr ls0) ls2))))
```

is `()` instead of `(2 3)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive call is wrong, replace it with

```
(loop (cdr ls0) ls2))))
```